# Etimología de “parte” (m.)

Tags: etimología

¿De dónde proviene el sustantivo “parte” (masculino), con el significado de “aviso, comunicación, despacho”? El DLE lista las distintas acepciones relacionadas a este concepto como si se tratase de la misma palabra que la forma femenina que significa “porción, división”, etc., y bajo el mismo origen etimológico (el latín *pars, partis*).

La palabra latina es femenina, pero el cambio de género en sí no me resulta extraño. Lo que no entiendo es la relación semántica que puede haber entre una acepción y la otra.

Comment: Excelente. Es algo tangencial, pero esto me hizo ver que _partisano_ viene también de este origen latino (aunque [a través del italiano "partigiano"](https://latrompetadejerico.com/etimologia/curiosidades-etimologicas-xiii/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La palabre *parte* (m.) con el significado de "comunicado" aparece en el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) incluso en 1566 (*Diálogo de la verdadera honra militar*, Jerónimo de Urrea):

> no dio **el parte** a nadie, y aquella noche caminó con presteza sin que hombre alguno entendiesse su camino

así que su uso parece ser antiguo. Dado que todos los diccionarios antiguos desde 1780 en el *[Mapa de diccionarios](https://webfrl.rae.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub)* clasifican *parte (m.)* y *parte (f.)* como la misma palabra, me aventuro a conjeturar que *un parte* significando "un comunicado" podría venir de la expresión *[dar parte](https://dle.rae.es/parte)*, que significa

> Notificar, dar cuenta a alguien de lo que ha sucedido.

y que también aparece en diccionarios desde al menos 1620, según el [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUIMenuNtlle?cmd=Lema&sec=1.0.0.0.0.). A su vez, *dar parte* quiere decir "hacer (a alguien) *partícipe* (de una información)", es decir, "hacerle ser parte de la información (o del grupo de personas que conocen la información)", con el significado femenino de *parte*. El uso de "participar" o "hacer partícipe" con el significado de "informar" fue discutido hace algún tiempo en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/35672/24236).

Comment: No mucho más que aportar, he consultado el _Corominas_ y no aclara el origen de la acepción masculina. Simplemente dice que _parte_ ya se usaba en los orígenes del idioma, hallándose en _El Cid_ (escrito alrededor del año 1200) y en las Glosas Emilianenses (finales del siglo X o principios del XI).

Comment: @Charlie veo que tu máquina del tiempo llega más lejos que la mía ;)

Comment: No conocía el *Mapa de diccionarios*, ¡gracias!